# free tool to generation traffic on web page

Tags: spring, statistics, vaadin, web-traffic

I use Spring and Vaadin. I need to test my application to know how it'll be working after release. I'm looking for some free tool which can generate some fake traffic and if possible give me some statistics (like response time, number of responses handled in an hour). Do you know any tools which can provide that? Are they provide any control what exactly will be executed (which button clicked, which pages entered)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at [JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/) It is dedicated to emulate static and dynamic loading.

Comment: Second that - I've already used this tool with success. For both functionality- and load testing. It's very easy to make elaborate Dos's with. :-)